# Ecto association with a condition

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's say I have two models, `Post` and `Comment` and the comment model can be 1 out of 2 types, `normal` and `fancy` which is defined by the column `type` in the `comments` table.

Now I want to add 2 associations on my `Post` model, where one refers to fancy comments and one to normal ones, how would I do it? So I want something like this:

```
has_many :fancy_comments, MyApp.Comment, where: [type: 0]
has_many :normal_comments, MyApp.Comment, where: [type: 1]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Until recently, this wasn't available in Ecto. The other answer to this question provides the current details. There was a lengthy discussion about how to add it [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/659).

In older versions of Ecto, you could use a composable query for this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Comment do
  
  ...schema, etc.

  def fancy(query) do
    from c in query,
      where: type == 0
  end

  def normal(query) do
    from c in query,
      where: type == 1
  end    
end
```

You can then use `has_many :comments, MyApp.Comment` and query based on that:

```
assoc(post, :comments) |> Comment.fancy() |> Repo.all()
```

Here is a blog post about [composable queries](http://blog.drewolson.org/composable-queries-ecto/).

You can also use a preload with a query:

```
fancy_query = from(c in Comments, where: type == 0)
Repo.preload(post, comments: fancy_query)
```

Comment: Don't you happen to know if it's possible to implement and if it's planned to be implemented? Not exactly `where` but something for filtering in general?

Comment: I am sure it is possible to implement - https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/659#issuecomment-121233468 would suggest that there are no plans for implementing it. The discussion moves towards using composable queries to achieve this like my first example.

Answer (score 6):

Conditional associations are now available in `Ecto`: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3-filtering-associations

```
defmodule Post do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "posts" do
    has_many :public_comments, Comment, where: [public: true]
  end
end
```