# Phoenix: has_many through with conditions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have following models:

```
defmodule My.User do
  use My.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    has_many :relationships, My.Relationship
    has_many :pending_friends, through: [:relationships, :friend]
    has_many :rejected_friends, through: [:relationships, :friend]
    has_many :friends, through: [:relationships, :friend]
    has_many :suggested_friends, through: [:relationships, :friend]

    timestamps()
  end
end


defmodule My.Relationship do
  use My.Web, :model

  schema "relationships" do
    belongs_to :user, My.User
    belongs_to :friend, My.User
    field :type, :integer

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Basically, user can have relationships with other users of different types.
My issue is that I am not able to preload the data correctly.

I was trying to find a way to either add constraint to "has_many" or write a query, which maps "relationships" data to 4 types, i.e. via "select" but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Last I checked Ecto didn't have support for adding conditions to `has_many` `through`. For the second approach, what query did you write that didn't work as expected?

Comment: @YuriDymov Please check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33297178/3102718  Does this work for you?

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants, thank you for your comment. I found this answer before posting new question and unfortunately it didn't work for me or at least I am doing something wrong. This was the one-to-many case and my is many-to-many (has_many through) and I was not able to make things work yet.

Comment: @Dogbert, well I tried different approaches but currently I barely can share anything, as I don't understand, how to write such queries. I.e. "from u in query, preload: :friends", I tried to write like " from u in query, preload: [friends: ^(from r in Relationship, where: r.type == 3)]" but obviously it didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use many_to_many? [What's new in Ecto 2.0](http://pages.plataformatec.com.br/ebook-whats-new-in-ecto-2-0) shows very well how to do it with new Ecto.

Comment: @helcim, I am using many_to_many in my code (has_many through actually implements it). If I am doing it wrong, please provide a code example, which will fit in my example. The whole idea is to preload part of many_to_many relotionships based on relationships type, and not all of them

Comment: @YuriDymov I see. Thanks for making it clear.